# "sudo systemctl enable docker" not available: Automatically run Docker at boot on WSL2 (using a "sysvinit" / "init" command or a workaround)

Tags: docker, service, systemd, wsl-2, systemctl

I am using Ubuntu on WSL2 (not on Docker Desktop).

According to [How to fix docker ‘Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?’ on Ubuntu](https://techoverflow.net/2018/12/15/how-to-fix-docker-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-ubuntu/), I can automatically start the docker daemon at boot using

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

instead of just starting it again at every boot with

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

with both commands avoiding "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?".

When using any of the two, I get

> Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with
> /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install. Executing:
> /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker

and a test run shows, that docker is not yet running:

> ```
> docker run hello-world
> ```
>
> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
> unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?. See
> 'docker run --help'.

Some steps before, I also got a different message at this point:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
> operate.Failed to connect to bus: Host is down"

which brought me to [Fixing "System has not been booted with systemd as init system" Error](https://linuxhandbook.com/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd/):

> Reason: Your Linux system is not using systemd
> How to know which init system you are using? You may use this command
> to know the process name associated with PID 1 (the first process that
> runs on your system):
>
> ```
> ps -p 1 -o comm=
> ```
>
> It should show systemd or sysv (or something like that) in the output.

`ps -p 1 -o comm=` gave me `init`.

According to this and this table

[image]

```
Systemd command
    Sysvinit command

systemctl start service_name
    service service_name start

systemctl stop service_name
    service service_name stop

systemctl restart service_name
    service service_name restart

systemctl status service_name
    service service_name status

systemctl enable service_name
    chkconfig service_name on

systemctl disable service_name
    chkconfig service_name off
```

I can choose `service docker start` to run docker, which works. But I cannot find something like "systemd"'s `sudo systemctl enable docker` for "sysvinit". I would expect it to be like:

```
sudo service docker enable
```

But that "enable" is not available for "sysvinit" / "init".

While `sudo service docker start` works like `sudo systemctl start docker`, there is no such command that uses "enable". At the moment, I need to run `sudo service docker start` whenever I start WSL2.

The question:

**What is the command that reaches `sudo systemctl enable docker` using `sudo service docker ...`, or if that does not exist, what is a workaround here to automatically start docker when opening Ubuntu on WSL2?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

*This answer requires the latest version of Windows and WSL at the time of this posting, and it now works under both Windows 10 and 11.  Run `wsl --version` and confirm that you are on WSL 1.0.0 (not to be confused with WSL1) or later.*

*If you are on an older release of Windows or WSL, then `wsl --version` will likely just show the Help text.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74655692/11810933) for information on how to upgrade.*

*If you cannot upgrade at this time, then please see my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814529/11810933) for a workaround for Windows 10.*

---

> what is a workaround here to automatically start docker when opening Ubuntu on WSL2?

- *Option 1:* Enable Systemd support in WSL2

  The latest release of WSL2 includes support for Systemd.  You can read how to enable it in [this Community Wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833858/11810933) or [my original Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986).

  However, my personal recommendation is to consider whether you really need Systemd.  It will add additional overhead and potentially other complications, and it isn't strictly necessary for Ubuntu to run (well) on WSL, as we've been doing for quite a few years without it.  Option 2 may be a better (and faster) option for many services.

  If you do have Systemd enabled, then the commands in the original question should work for you:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable docker
  sudo systemctl start docker
  ```

  Docker Engine should automatically start for you the next time you restart your WSL2 distribution.  However, please see the bottom of this answer for an important note on *keeping* the services running.

---

- *Option 2:*  Add the necessary commands to the `[boot]` section in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

  ```
  [boot]
  command= service docker start
  ```

  To run multiple commands, separate them with a semicolon as in:

  ```
  [boot]
  command= service docker start; service cron start
  ```

**Important Note**: If you run a service (e.g. `cron` or `docker`) using *either* of these methods, please note that the WSL distribution will still auto-terminate when the last process that was started *interactively* completes.  You can see more discussion (and a workaround using `keychain`) for this in my answer to the Ask Ubuntu question [Is it possible to run a WSL app in the background?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1435938/1165986).

Comment: "It will add additional overhead and potentially other complications" - I'm roughly intermediate level at Linux, and was curious what overhead it adds?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Re:overhead -- Systemd automatically starts many services that you may not need.  Before enabling Systemd on WSL2, I count 5 services running by default at startup.  After enabling Systemd, that number goes up to 34.  Some of these can be disabled, as they simply aren't needed (e.g. `wpa-supplicant`, which is used to configure wireless networks in Ubuntu), but that does require some additional effort.  Also, while the Systemd support is getting better, it still continues to be a source of many issues (and fixes) in recent WSL2 releases.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Honestly, that's probably worth a question all-by-itself, but it might be tough to word it just the right way to avoid "opinion".  Also, if you do, I'd recommend asking on [Ask Ubuntu](askubuntu.com) (assuming you are running Ubuntu) since the Mods there draw the "subjective" line a bit further than here ;-).

Answer (score 58):

---

*Important note:  Most users should read [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74662813/11810933) first.  This answer is a bit outdated, but I'm leaving it here in case it's beneficial to anyone running on an older WSL release.*

---

Short answer to "*what is a workaround here to automatically start docker when opening Ubuntu on WSL2?*

- *Option 1:*  On Windows 11, add the necessary commands to the `[boot]` section in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

  ```
  [boot]
  command="service docker start"
  ```

  Note that under the latest Preview releases, there appears to be [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8661) that causes anything started via this `boot.command` to terminate when no services that were started via an actual command-line are still running.  In other words, if you need Docker (or any other service) to continue to run after you exit your WSL2 session, you'll probably need to use Option 2 (or uninstall the Preview).
- *Option 2:* On Windows 10, run the necessary commands in your *user* startup scripts (e.g. `.profile`).  Do it with a check to see if the service is running first, like:

  ```
  wsl.exe -u root -e sh -c "service docker status || service docker start"
  ```

  This is a better alternative than my previous answer (option 3, below) since it doesn't require modification to `sudoers`.  This takes advantage of the fact that the `wsl.exe` command can be run from inside WSL, using the `-u root` option to run the commands as root without a password.

  Note: If for some reason this command fails, your default WSL distribution may be different than you expect.  Check the output of `wsl.exe -l -v`.  You can change the default distro using `wsl.exe --setdefault <distro_name>` or adjust the commandline above to specify the distro with `-d <distro_name>`.
- *Option 3:* (old answer, here for posterity): `visudo` or add rules to `/etc/sudoers.d` to allow your user to run the commands without a password:

  ```
  username ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service docker *
  ```

  Then edit your `.profile` to add:

  ```
  sudo service docker status || sudo service docker start
  ```

### More Details:

As you've discovered, WSL does not include any systemd support, nor really any direct support for starting a service on boot.

For starters, the WSL subsystem doesn't launch at Windows boot, but only when the user launches a login session anyway.  So without any real "system start", the init.d or systemd startup doesn't make as much sense.

Further, users may have multiple WSL instances/distributions running, and if you are doing that (as I am), then you really don't want *all* services from *all* instances running on every boot (although, updated answer, Windows 11 does now give us this option).

For Docker, though, are you running Docker Desktop with WSL2 integration, or just installed directly into a WSL2 instance?  For Docker Desktop, I ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467740/10692741) in another question yesterday on how to start Docker Desktop daemon at Windows boot.

You can also have the WSL2 instance start via Windows Task Manager when the user logs in, and run the script via something like `wsl -u root service docker start` in the Task Manager.

Note that the same doesn't seem to work at Windows *boot*, however, (only *login*) because Windows seems to terminate any WSL instance that isn't tied to an active user after a few seconds (even if a service is running in the background).  You can work around this with the PowerShell `Invoke-WmiMethod`, something like ...

`powershell.exe Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList 'wsl'`, although I haven't tested this all that thoroughly.

Comment: Worked for me adding `sudo service docker status || sudo service docker start` to my ~/.profile on my WSL2 Linux drive. Afterwards, `sudo docker run hello-world` runs. You are right, it seems logical that docker is not started automtically since you do not always need it ;). And as to your question, I run Docker installed directly into a WSL2 instance.

Comment: Option 1 worked perfectly. I'm on Windows 11 and have Docker installed directly onto my WSL2 Ubuntu instance. thanks @NotTheDro1ds

Comment: For some reason option 2 works intermittently for me. `wsl.exe -u root -e sh -c "service docker status || service docker start"` sometimes is working fine. Then I backup and restore wsl and everything is okay, except that line then gives `sh: service: not found` (x2). Oddly enough, after a ~week usage it started working again, idk why. Then I needed to transfer WSL (bkp/restore) again and it stopped working again. Win 10, WSL2. Tried troubleshooting but no luck.

Comment: @ViníciusM If the `service` command isn't being found, then my first guess would be that the `PATH` isn't set correctly, of course.  You can check (using the same process) with `wsl.exe -u root -e sh -c 'echo $PATH'`.  Second guess - Have you at any point installed a Systemd script (Genie?  Distrod?  Etc.)?  I'm wondering if it is getting activated sometimes.  When Systemd is active, the service command uses `systemctl` internally.  Note that once Systemd is activated, some parts of it change *all* instances -- So even if you run it in another WSL distribution, it could impact this one.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds PATH check outputs `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:` plus some windows folders; I can correctly call `service` in terminal on both my user and as root (after `sudo su -`). It's just from the wsl.exe call that it fails. And about the Systemd script: nope. Never installed anything. I run away scared from stuff that could cause "more unpredictable behaviour" and "troubleshooting" hehe

Comment: @ViníciusM Ah, sorry.  I *think* I know what's going on here.  When you "backup and restore", I assume you are doing this through `--export`/`--import`?  And perhaps `--unregister` between?  In that case, I think another distribution gets set as default (perhaps Docker?).  If the problem that you mentioned is currently happening, check `wsl -l -v` to confirm the default distro.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds That was precisely it! `wsl --setdefault Ubuntu` fixed it! Maybe worth making a small footnote somewhere? I've made a quick edit suggest. =)

Comment: For the Windows 10 solution, I redirected output to dev/null `wsl.exe -u root -e sh -c "service docker status || service docker start" >/dev/null 2>&1`. Another small note, the `.profile` file is opened from *within* a WSL terminal (not PowerShell, CMD, etc). For example, using `nano ~/.profile`.

Comment: @dana Just a heads-up, since your comment here pulled me to this answer -- My answer is a bit outdated, and I'll try to update it soon.  On Windows 10, you can now use the same solution as on Windows 11.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74655692/11810933) for how to upgrade to the latest WSL release that can do this on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

In WSL2 Ubuntu

1. Create or modify the /etc/wsl.conf file with sudo and add:

```bash
[boot]
systemd=true
```

2. Enable the Docker daemon on boot:

```bash
systemctl enable docker
```

3. Create a Docker group and add your user so it can run without sudo

```bash
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

4. Restart your WSL environment :

```bash
wsl --shutdown
```

Comment: Great, we can use systemd now. Additional info in "Advanced settings configuration in WSL" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#systemd-support

Answer (score 0):

This worked for WSL ubuntu:

Before:

`service --status-all`

[ - ]  ssh

`service ssh start`

After:

`service --status-all`

[ + ]  ssh

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).