# Installing docker on WSL 2 Windows - Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS(focal)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Getting the following error when trying to start docker on WSL Windows 11

```
"System has not been booted with systemd as init system"
```

Comment: Just a heads-up that this information is already covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65813979/sudo-systemctl-enable-docker-not-available-automatically-run-docker-at-boot-o).  It's in the question itself, rather than an answer, but I touch on it again in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow all these steps from the original Docker docs:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#installation-methods

However, because in WSL we may run into something like this when trying to start Docker:

> `"System has not been booted with systemd as init system"`

Here's the reason why: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/system-not-booted-with-systemd-as-init.html

Use the following command

```
sudo service docker start
```