# What is the entry point for WSL 1?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Imagine we have a statically linked Linux executable.

How should I name it in the imported tar.gz so the WSL 1 will run it by default, when created and started like:

```
# import an archive as a WSL distro
wsl --import static tmp-root-dir static.tar.gz
# boot distro to a default app??
wsl -d static
```

**PS** WSL uses own proprietary boot process and seems doesn't use traditional Unix `/sbin/init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer:*

The smallest bootable (without errors or warnings) WSL rootfs will consist of three files:

- `/main`: Your statically-linked application.  It can be named whatever you want, as long as the name matches what is in `passwd`.
- `/etc/passwd`: Defines the application (i.e. shell) to load for the default user.
- `/etc/wsl.conf`:  To suppress normal WSL functionality and (optionally) define the non-root user.

*More detail:*

This probably isn't *exactly* what you are wanting, but it will hopefully meet your needs.

To start with, the entry point for WSL (the first time a Linux ELF binary is started inside the instance) seems to be its `/init` binary, which, in addition to some "normal" Linux init process tasks, sets up some of the Windows-interop functionality.  To my knowledge, it cannot currently be changed.  As far as I can tell, for WSL1, it is injected into the instance by the LXSS manager when starting a WSL instance.

Note:  WSL2 *might* be slightly different in this regard, as it does seem to use a kernel-processed initrd to load `/init`.  It is possible to override the kernel command-line, but that would impact *all* WSL2 instances, so it's probably not a practical solution.

It's not quite clear from your question whether you want the "default application" to:

- Run as the default application/shell every time `wsl -d static` is run, even if it was already running.
- Or just run once when starting the WSL1 instance for the first time.

I believe you are looking for the first option.

##### Run as the default application

In the first case, the standard WSL1 `/init` process might get you to where you need to be.  As part of the startup, as you would expect, it reads `/etc/passwd` to determine the user shell to start.  It also reads `/etc/wsl.conf` to determine the default user ID (but falls back to the registry if there is no default user set in `wsl.conf`).

So, to start a different application (let's call it `main`), you can:

- Place the binary in the root directory of your image.
- Set the application as the "shell" of the root user in a single-line `/etc/passwd`:

  ```
  user:x:1000:1000:user:/:/main
  ```

  Side-note that this also sets the home directory to `/` so we don't have to create another directory.
- Define a `etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

  ```
  [user]
  default=user

  [automount]
  enabled=false
  mountFsTab=false

  [interop]
  appendWindowsPath=false
  ```

  This will prevent WSL from performing the following startup tasks, which would produce an error without additional image support:

  - Mounting Windows drives into the instance
  - Attempting to process `/etc/fstab` (since we have no `mount` command in the image).
  - Appending Windows paths (since our instance won't have access to the Windows drives)

  It also sets the default user to the UID 1000 user we created in `/etc/passwd`.  This isn't strictly necessary - There's likely no concern with running as root in this single-use instance, but I've included a non-root user as a "best practice".

That should be it.  The smallest bootable WSL rootfs will consist of just those three files:

```
/etc/wsl.conf
/etc/passwd
/main
```

This will work on WSL1 as well as WSL2, although for WSL2, you should invoke with `wsl ~ -d static` to make sure that it doesn't try to start on a Windows drive that it can't access.  Otherwise, you'll receive an init error, but your application will still be invoked.

##### Run once

If you are looking for something that will, for instance, start up a daemon when the instance is started for the first time, then there are a few alternatives that I document in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814529/11810933).  If you are on Windows 11, then there's a built-in mechanism via `/etc/wsl.conf`.  Otherwise, on Windows 10, you'll probably need to include some binary that can handle conditional logic.  Something like [execline](https://skarnet.org/software/execline/) would probably be perfect for this, but I've had issues with it under WSL2, at least, and I'm not sure that it would run under WSL1 (but it might).

##### Side-note for WSL1/musl

[musl](https://musl.libc.org) is a commonly used alternative libc implementation.  For instance, Rust (AFAICT), can only generate truly statically-linked executables using musl.  Note, however, that WSL1 cannot run musl-based statically linked binaries.

WSL2 can handle them just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. Initially I missed an executable bit on the app when created TAR archive.

Take standard 64-bit assembly:

```
.data
msg:
  .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
  .set len, . - msg

.text

.globl _start
_start:
  # write
  mov  $1,   %rax
  mov  $1,   %rdi
  mov  $msg, %rsi
  mov  $len, %rdx
  syscall

  # exit
  mov  $60, %rax
  xor  %rdi, %rdi
  syscall
```

and create a minimal WSL system:

```sh
wsl as -64 -o minimal.o minimal.s
wsl ld -melf_x86_64 -o minimal minimal.o
tar czf minimal.tar.gz \
  --mode=a=rx \
  --xform='s#^minimal#/\0#' minimal
wsl --import minimal rootfs-minimal minimal.tar.gz --version 1
wsl --list
wsl -d minimal -e /minimal
```

To make executable *default* (shorten `wsl -d minimal -e /minimal` to `wsl -d minimal`) we need an extra file `/etc/passwd`:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/minimal
```

*First line* of this file determine a default user and so path to the executable (entry point) unless you override the user with `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[user]
default=user
```

Basically WSL 1 treats only 2 files as magical (in addition to ignoring `/sbin/init`):

- `/etc/wsl.conf`
- `/etc/passwd`